# MathJax and rendering of brackets

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax

I am working with a mixture of LaTeX and calculator math input and MathJax output on a website. I have been trying to figure out how to get MathJax to display the brackets around expressions like 5^(x) and A/(2*pi*h + 2*pi).

The ASCIIMath input assumes () to be grouping when a user has ^ or / in their input and so does not show the brackets. These brackets need to be escaped using (( and )). This then affects if a user inputs mismatched brackets. Since the site this is on is aimed at teaching kids maths it is important they see what they are typing in clearly.

Does anyone have some sort of solution for me? I have currently got an extension to MathJax (written in plain JS) that converts some of the input to more correct ASCIIMath that can then be processed correctly.

The best MWE I can give is given below in my edit to this post.

**Edit**
I have the following JS code that is almost working but produces unexpected results in a few cases:

```js
filterExponentBrackets: function (str) {
      if ((/\^|\/|sqrt/g).test(str)) {
        if ((/\(|\)/g).test(str)) {
          var openingBrackets = str.split("(").length-1;
              closingBrackets = str.split(")").length-1;
              startString = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('('));
              midString = str.substr(str.indexOf('('), str.indexOf(')'));
              endString = str.substr(str.indexOf(')') + closingBrackets);
          if (openingBrackets === closingBrackets) {
              str = startString + '(' + midString + ')' + endString;
          } else {
            if (openingBrackets < closingBrackets) {
              // Some issues here around no opening and some closing
              str = startString + '(' + midString + ')' + endString;
            } else {
              // Think a bit more about this case, need to not show the frac or sqrt or ^
              str = str;
            }
          }
        }
      }
  return str;
  }
```

And the following mocha tests:

```js
describe('Mismatched bracket fixes', function() {
    it('Fractions with extra closing brackets', function () {
      assert.equal(mathsFilters.filterExponentBrackets("A/(2*pi*h+2*h))"), "A/((2*pi*h+2*h)))")
    });

    it('Fractions with extra opening brackets', function () {
      assert.equal(mathsFilters.filterExponentBrackets("A/((2*pi*h+2*h)"), "A/((2*pi*h+2*h)))")
    });

    it('Fractions with equal opening and closing brackets', function () {
      assert.equal(mathsFilters.filterExponentBrackets("A/(2*pi*h+2*h)"), "A/((2*pi*h+2*h))")
    });

    it('Fractions with only closing brackets', function () {
      assert.equal(mathsFilters.filterExponentBrackets("A/2*pi*h+2*h)"), "A/2*pi*h+2*h)")
    });

    it('Fractions with only opening brackets', function () {
      assert.equal(mathsFilters.filterExponentBrackets("A/(2*pi*h+2*h"), "A/(2*pi*h+2*h")
    });
  });
```

The extra opening brackets and cases where there are only opening or only closing brackets are not quite right. For only opening or closing brackets the fraction should be A/2 stuff. Extra opening brackets needs to somehow show those extra brackets.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that MathJax introduces these duplicate brackets; it would show up very quickly on sites like math.SE. My guess would be that some processing step adds them before MathJax gets to them. You can test this by using the Menu to get the source. Without a sample, there's not much people can help you with though.

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are indeed correct. MathJax is not at fault here. The issue lies in ASCIIMath input for MathJax. ASCIIMath assumes users mean () as grouping elements and so does not display them when used in combination with / or ^. In these cases I need to escape the brackets with (( and )) to get them to display.
I realise my post was not very clear, the brackets are going missing not being added, I have edited accordingly